# Occuring issue while passing data between classes

Tags: ios, json, swift2, xcode7, alamofire

I'm trying to pass data from my Data class to my Login class (both files are separate.), but it throws 2 errors from "Login" class as it appears unable to receive the data

Below are the errors shown in Login.swift :

**Error 1**

> Instance member 'dataObj' cannot be used on type 'Login'

**Error 2**

> Expected declaration

**Login.swift code**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
class Login {let dataObj = Data(userName: "username", passWord: "password")

let endPoint = dataObj.todoEndPoint
let parameters = [
    "username": dataObj.userName,
    "password": dataObj.passWord
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, endPoint, parameters:parameters)
.responseJSON { response in
print(response.request)
print(response.response)
print(response.result)
if let JSON = response.result.value {
print("Did receive JSON data: \(JSON)")
}
else {
print("JSON data is nil.")
}
}   
}
```

**Data.swift code**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class Data {

var userName:String!
var passWord:String!
let todoEndpoint: String = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"

init(userName : String, passWord : String) {
    self.userName = userName
    self.passWord = passWord
}
}
```

**Screenshot of errors**

[image: Login.swift errors]

Comment: I don't know much about Swift, but shouldn't you instantiate a "Data" object first before you can access the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change the Data instance property to class property by using static

```
class Data {

static var userName:String!
static var passWord:String! 
static let todoEndpoint: String = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"

}
```

and set direct values in `userName` and `passWord`.

in from login set value

```
Data.userName = "yourusername" 
Data.passWord = "password"
```

**2.**
or you can also create Data object

```
class Data {

 var userName:String!
 var passWord:String!
 let todoEndpoint: String = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"

init(userName : String, passWord : String) {

 self.userName = userName 
 self.passWord = passWord
}
```

and in login class

```
class Login {
static let dataObj = Data(userName: "usename", passWord: "password")

lazy var endPoint = Login.dataObj.todoEndpoint

let parameters = [
           "username": dataObj.userName,
           "password": dataObj.passWord
]


func getRequest() {

Alamofire.request(.POST, endPoint, parameters:parameters)
    .responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)
        print(response.response)
        print(response.result)
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("Did receive JSON data: \(JSON)")
        }
        else {
            print("JSON data is nil.")
        }
}
}

}
```

**UPDATED**

I guess you should create a singleton object  to get a values of users everywhere.

```
class Data {

 static let sharedInstance = Data()
 static let todoEndpoint: String = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
 var userName: String?
 var passWord: String?

 // for prevent from creating this class object
 private init() { }

 }
```

And in Login class.

```
class Login {

 init(userName: String, passWord: String) {
 Data.sharedInstance.userName = userName
 Data.sharedInstance.passWord = passWord
  }

 /// call this method to login
 func getRequest() {
 print(Data.sharedInstance.userName)
 print(Data.sharedInstance.passWord) 

 Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.endPoint, parameters: ["userName": Data.sharedInstance.userName, "passWord": Data.sharedInstance.passWord])
.responseJSON { response in
print(response.request)
print(response.response)
print(response.result)
if let JSON = response.result.value {
print("Did receive JSON data: \(JSON)")
}
else {
print("JSON data is nil.")
}

}

}
}
```

And from some other class create a Login instance and pass `userName` and `Password` values from there and call getRequest method using Login object.

Comment: Hi @Sahil Beri I've tried following your solution but my Login.swift code is now throwing up some new errors as shown in my updated post. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: use `lazy var endPoint = dataObj.todoEndpoint` and create singleton Data object  and second error is thrown because you are fire request in class scope . create a method and call it from somewhere.

Comment: I'm getting an "instance member 'endPoint' cannot be used on type 'Login' error now at my alamofire request line. Do you how I can fix it?

Comment: because we are using it in static method.

Comment: which print outputs? if you want to print `userName`  use print(Data.sharedInstance.userName)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111378/discussion-between-sahil-beri-and-noobdev).

Answer (score 0):

According to your `Data` class implementation you should use it like :

```
class Login {
let dataObj = Data(userName : "username", passWord : "password")
let endPoint = dataObj.todoEndPoint
let parameters = [
               "username": dataObj.userName,
               "password": dataObj.passWord
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, endPoint, parameters:parameters)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.result)
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("Did receive JSON data: \(JSON)")
            }
            else {
                print("JSON data is nil.")
            }

    }

    }
```

If you want to get static data from `Data` then use `singleton/shared instance`.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Yawar Ali I've tried following your solution and was thrown a couple of "Instance member cannot be used on type instance errors" in my Login.swift. Can you please tell me how to resolve them?

Comment: try `lazy let endPoint = dataObj.todoEndPoint`

Comment: Sure, that helped with the "Instance member cannot be used on type instance" errors but I'm still being thrown the "expected declaration" error beside my Alamofire.request line

Comment: I would prefer to use a method with params to call service of login in that case you will not experience any issue. I am not sure why you are putting data to `Data` class and then using it for requesting ?

Comment: i agree with @MuhammadYawarAli. i'm also not getting why are you doing this @noobdev?

Comment: This is because I felt that having my alamofire requests inside an init was a bad approach and so wanted to take it out

Comment: then call it with parameters to avoid initialization delay issue.

Comment: @noobdev check my answer now.